# python pandas indexing mess up scipy.interpolate.lagrange

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have an excel spreadsheet that looks like this:
[excel spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AH6W.png)

I just started learning python and used pandas to read the excel file. I want to interpolate the data in the spreadsheet and have done it like so:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import lagrange
df = pd.read_excel('excel.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
x1 = df.loc[df['Header1']==1, 'Header2']
y1 = df.loc[df['Header1']==1, 'Header3']
poly1 = lagrange(x1,y1)
x2 = df.loc[df['Header1']==2, 'Header2']
y2 = df.loc[df['Header1']==2, 'Header3']
poly2 = lagrange(x2,y2)
```

poly1 works but poly2 gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 75, in lagrange
  pt = poly1d(w[j])
File "/u/q/kyp24/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 767, in __getitem__
  result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
File "/u/q/kyp24/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3118, in get_value
  tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 106, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 114, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 964, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

I noticed that the index for x1,y1 are 0,1,2 and for x2,y2 are 4,5,6,7,8. I changed the index for x2,y2 to 0,1,2,3,4 and then poly2 works. My question is why is this so? And is there a way of not changing the index but still make it work?

Edit: below is the DataFrame as a python dictionary

```
{u'Header2': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 3.0, 3: nan, 4: 1.0, 5: 2.0, 6: 3.0, 7: 4.0, 8: 5.0}, u'Header3': {0: 1.0, 1: 4.0, 2: 9.0, 3: nan, 4: 1.0, 5: 8.0, 6: 27.0, 7: 64.0, 8: 125.0}, u'Header1': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: nan, 4: 2.0, 5: 2.0, 6: 2.0, 7: 2.0, 8: 2.0}}
```

Comment: Could you copy your DataFrame as a python dictionary in a code block in your question using ([pandas.DataFrame.to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)), so we can easily copy-paste and run your example.   (There is also [DataFrame.to_clipboard](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_clipboard.html) but it is maybe less practical.)

Comment: @xdze2 I have done as you requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the interpolation function is confused by the Pandas Series type of data. Try explicitly converting it to a Numpy array using [pandas.Series.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
x1 = df.loc[df['Header1']==1, 'Header2'].values
y1 = df.loc[df['Header1']==1, 'Header3'].values
poly1 = lagrange(x1,y1)

# note:
type(df.loc[df['Header1']==1, 'Header2'])  # pandas.core.series.Series
type(df.loc[df['Header1']==1, 'Header2'].values)  # numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you for your quick response.